# How to commonly address primitives and objects

Tags: java, reflection, primitive, autoboxing

Here is a utility method I have:

```
public static Class<?>[] getTypes(Object[] objects){
    Class<?>[] types = new Class<?>[objects.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        types[i] = objects[i].getClass();
    }

    return types;
}
```

And here is a test case that **fails**:

```
@Test
public void getTypesTest() {
    Object[] objects = {"String", new StringBuilder(), new Integer(5), 5};

    Class<?>[] classes = ReflectionUtils.getTypes(objects);
    assertTrue(classes[0].equals(String.class));
    assertTrue(classes[1].equals(StringBuilder.class));
    assertTrue(classes[2].equals(Integer.class));
    assertTrue(classes[3].equals(int.class)); // Fails here
}
```

I realize that **when I pass `5` within `Object[]`, this is Boxed to `new Integer(5)`**.

How can I get the behavior I am expecting?

**Edit**

What I am expecting: The assertion that fails in my test will pass. What should I do with the method under test to achieve that?:

Comment: The test will always fail... what are you trying to achieve on a high level (what real-world problem do you want to solve)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot treat a primitive as an object as this is what defines a primitive as different to an object. By having an array of objects, you are ensuring everything in it is an object, not a primitive.

---

An `int` is not an object so you can't put it in an `Object[]` so the compiler will generate code to auto-box you value of 5. i.e. it calls `Integer.valueOf(5)` which is more efficient than `new Integer(5)` but is still an object.

You can't call `.equals()` on a primitive so the fact this compiles tells you its not.

BTW you can use `int.class` to get the class of `int`.

> How can I get the behavior I am expecting?

Can you say exactly what you are expecting in English?

---

For those interested, the code for Integer.valueOf(int) in Java 6 and 7

```
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    assert IntegerCache.high >= 127;
    if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
    return new Integer(i);
}
```

Comment: I never knew there is something like `primitive.class`!: Edited the question. -- What you explained is what I know (although with a misconception). I have told that in *bold* in my last paragraph of the question.
-- *"You can't call `.equals()` on a primitive so the fact this compiles tells you its not."*: It is not on the `primitive`. Its on the `Class<?>`.
-- *"Can you say exactly what you are expecting in English?"* : I thought it was clear, edited the question.

Comment: *"...`Integer.valueOf(5)` which is more efficient than `new Integer(5)`"*-- No way. You may check the source to find that the first one invokes the second one.

Comment: @Mohayemin This was true in Java 5.0

Comment: @Mohayemin The point I was trying to make is; a primitive is not an object and never will be, so that line will never work.  What is the real purpose behind this and perhaps that can be done another way.

Comment: I understand now why you said that. So, you say we cannot commonly address as I expect? State this in your answer so that I can accept that. :) I hate questions with unaccepted answers. :P

Comment: Peter, do you have any idea why they would write `i + (-IntegerCache.low)`? Whatever code I look at in the JDK, there's yet another mystery :)

Comment: The cache hold negative numbers from -128. You can't start an array index at -128 but you can add 128 to the index of every value. This says you have to add the negative of the first value (which is actually negative)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it fails is that you have an array of object. A value of primitive type `int` gets [auto-boxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) as `Integer` and so the array contains an instance of `Integer` at the 3rd position. You can make the test pass by replacing

```
assertTrue(classes[3].equals(int.class)); // Fails here
```

with

```
assertTrue(classes[3].equals(Integer.class));
```

Comment: What is the point of changing the test case to make it pass!!! Also, I know why it did not work. And also, [Peter's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11912739/887149) already stated what you said.

Comment: @Mohayemin You asked for what to do to make the test pass. I believe this is a correct solution - your test isn't correct at that place so the only solution is to correct it. As Peter already mentioned, the reason is that you cannot put unboxed `int` into `Object[]`, so no matter what you do , `assertTrue(classes[3].equals(int.class))` will always fail, when you generate the array of classes from `Object[]`. [And I didn't know about the other answers until I posted mine.]